# Dialog's floating button remains overlaping

Tags: html, css, .net, blazor, maui

Hi I am building a Maui blazor application and I have a full page size Dialog which has a floating button. When the dialog is closed and go back the original page, on the original page there is a dead area exactly where the dialog's button was (On the dialog I change the visibility of that button based on a condition).
This style I am using for the floating button:

```
.center {
    bottom: 5%;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

update:
I changed the css of the floating button now there is no dead area but the position is not good.:

```
.center {
    bottom: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to set whether or not an element is visible.

One way is to set `visibility` to `hidden`. Then HTML elements will hide but keep the space where that element is located.

Another way is to set `display`  to `none`. In this condition, HTML Elements hides but does not preserve the space in which that element resides.

So, you can try to use `display` and set the value of it to `none`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: FabExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FabExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const FabExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FloatingActionButton Sample'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not a Flutter app.